# Modifying a value in a table using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have only just begun to learn procedures in SQL. I have hit a bit of a wall and can't seem to come to a fix. I am trying to create a procedure that will allow me to pass the item description and a percentage of how much I would like to increase that items price. This is the code I have got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADJUST_PRICE(
pItemDesc IN ITEM.ItemDesc%TYPE,
percentage IN NUMBER)
IS
pItemPrice NUMBER;
incAmt NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT itemprice into pItemPrice
FROM item WHERE itemdesc LIKE '%pItemDesc%';
incAmt := (pItemPrice*percentage)/100;
pItemPrice := incAmt + pItemPrice;
UPDATE Item
SET ItemPrice = pItemPrice
WHERE ItemDesc LIKE '%pItemDesc%';
END;
```

The procedure will compile but will not accept my calling block:

```
BEGIN 
ADJUST_PRICE('%Dish%', 10);
END;
```

The error report I receive:

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "S270131.ADJUST_PRICE", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 2
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thankyou.

Comment: If you compare with the `like` operator as you do, `like '%pItemDesc%`, that will only match items that literally contain the substring `pItemDesc` in their description (which, probably, means no such items exist). In that context, you are not referencing your variable at all. Instead, compare to `'%' || pItemDesc || '%'`. And don't include the percent signs again when you call the procedure. Not sure if there are other mistakes, too, but this is the obvious one that causes `no_data_found`.

Comment: Have you thought about what *should* happen, if there no matching items? And what, if there are more than one?

Comment: @mathguy yeah I see what I've done there now yeah that was silly of me cheers, still isn't working but atleast I am closer now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to hit the `ITEM` table twice. Firstly, in a multi-user system, the details could have changed between your initial query and the update. Secondly it's inefficient, as it does twice as much work as it needs to.

I would simplify it to something like this:

```
create or replace procedure adjust_price
    ( p_itemdesc  in item.itemdesc%type
    , p_percentage in number )
as
    l_increase_factor number := p_percentage/100 + 1;
begin
    update item i
    set    i.itemprice = i.itemprice * l_increase_factor
    where  itemdesc like '%'||p_itemdesc||'%' escape '\';
end;
```

I have included an escape character to allow callers to treat wildcard characters `%` and `_` as literals if they need to.

I've converted the percentage to a multiplication factor, so for example 50 percent becomes 1.5, rather than multiplying the price by the percentage, dividing by 100, and adding the original price, as I find that clearer arithmetically, but that's just my personal preference.

You used a `p` prefix for one of your two parameters (`pItemDesc`) and also for a local variable (`pItemPrice`). Code becomes confusing if variables are named like parameters and parameters are named like variables, so I recommend choosing one naming strategy and sticking with it.

Notice that code is easier to follow, work with and fix if it is neatly laid out, so I strongly recommend formatting like a programmer.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the well explained and easy to read code. I really like the way you laid it out and I will try to do similar in the future. Yeah you're right that way of coming to a percentage is much cleaner, I will definitely be putting that to use again, cheers William.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL doesn't support this kind of string interpolation that you have in mind. But just use your input parameter as a bind variable instead:

```sql
SELECT ItemPrice
INTO pItemPrice
FROM Item 
WHERE ItemDesc LIKE pItemDesc;
```

You'll still get `NO_DATA_FOUND` exceptions if your procedure doesn't find anything. But you don't actually need the extra `SELECT`. Just run the `UPDATE` directly:

```sql
UPDATE Item
SET ItemPrice = (ItemPrice * percentage) / 100 + ItemPrice
WHERE ItemDesc LIKE pItemDesc;
```